# How to add onto url if url contains string in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After doing some digging on my WordPress site, I'm pretty confident that adding the string '&post_type=product' to the end of a search URL changes an Elementor search to a WooCommerce search. I'm unsure, however, how to implement this change?

What I want to do is add some code to functions.php which checks if there is some '?s=' substring in a URL and if there is one, it adds '&post_type=product' at the end of the URL.

Could someone show me how this is done?

Comment: Something like https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function your_custom_function(){
    $string = isset($_GET['s'])?$_GET['s']:"";
    if($string == "your_string_name"){
        global $wp;
        $new_url = $wp->request."?s=".$string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;
</script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you if not please explain me more about your query

Comment: Thanks for the help man, the code you sent didn't quite work so I've modified it a bit however nothing is happening. This is the code I've got now:

Comment: ```add_filter('site_url','wpse_search_filter');
function wpse_search_filter(){
    $string = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(str_contains($string, "?s=")){
        $new_url = $string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;
</script>
    <?php
    }   
}```

Comment: I can't get this to work though, it doesn't do anything

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Update your permalink and
add:

```
<input type="text" name="post_type" value="product" />

<?php 
    function your_custom_function(){ 
        $string = isset($_GET['s'])?$_GET['s']:"";
        if($string == "your_string_name"){
            global $wp;
            $new_url = $wp->request."?s=".$string."&post_type=product";
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;
 </script>
 <?php
 }
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: <input type="text" name="post_type" name="product" />

Comment: What do you mean? This isn't very clear.

Comment: I apologize for my incorrect answer , Now I have solution of your question I

Comment: <?php
function your_custom_function(){
    $string = isset($_GET['s'])?$_GET['s']:"";
    if($string == "your_string_name"){
        global $wp;
        $new_url = $wp->request."?s=".$string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;
</script>
    <?php
    }
}